# Chevra Kaddisha string locations

Tags: minhag, death, funeral-burial-levaya, tying-knots-kosheir

I recently did a tahara and I was curious about where a lot of the practices came from and what the meaning behind them is.

One thing we did was we tied strings around various locations of the deceased.  We tied a string over the *tachrichim* (shrouds) around each leg right above the ankles, and around the waist.  We also tied the neck of the shirt closed, but I don't know if that was for the sake of tying a string or just for the sake of closing the neck of the shirt.

Why are these strings tied at these locations?

Comment: Those sound like the locations regular clothes are tighter at.

Comment: @DoubleAA your pants are tight right above your ankles?  My clothes are loosest right there.